# How to prevent Bootstrap DD DT to dropping to next line?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have the following code where the DD DT is on the same line:

```
<dl class="row">
   <dt class="col-sm-2">Arahat</dt>
   <dd class="col-sm-10">The "Perfected One", who has overcome The Three Poisons of Desire, Hatred and Ignorance. </dd>
   <dt class="col-sm-2">Bodhi</dt>
   <dd class="col-sm-10">Awakened wisdom.</dd>
   <dt class="col-sm-2">Zen</dt>
   <dd class="col-sm-10">Meditative absorption in which all dualistic distinctions are eliminated.</dd>
</dl>
```

On the mobile screen, it collapses to one below other. How can I prevent that?

[image]

How I want it to stay on mobile screen.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of class="row" use  class="dl-horizontal"
Also remove col-sm from all DD and DT Tag and use Bootstrap 3

Comment: from Bootstrap 4 documentation: .dl-horizontal has been dropped. Instead, use .row on <dl> and use grid column classes (or mixins) on its <dt> and <dd> children.

Comment: I have not tried this for bootstrap 4 yet. If it is not working, try to do by  adding little css to your code and achieve same in bootstrap 4 also.